# While inside while and 2 result

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

```
<?php
                 $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
                 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                  {
                 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                  }
                  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM itiraf");
                  $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT oy FROM users WHERE username='". $Account->session('display_name') ."'");
               if(mysqli_num_rows($result)=="0"){echo "Henüz itiraf yapılmamış";} 
                  else{
                  echo "<table border='1' class='imagetable'>
                  <tr>
                  <th>NO:</th>
                  <th>İsim</th>
                  <th>İtiraf</th>
                  <th>Oy</th>
                  <th>Oy Kullan</th>
                  </tr>";

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td><b>" . $row['id'] . "</b></td>";
                   echo "<td><b>" . $row['username'] . "</b></td>";
                   echo "<td><b>" . $row['itiraf'] . "</b><br></td>";
                   echo "<td><b>" . $row['oy'] . "</b><br></th>";

                   while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
                         if ($row2['oy'] ==10) { echo "<td>Oy kullandınız</td>";}
                              else{echo "<td><a href='oy.php?id={$row[id]}'><img src='assets/images/up.png'/></a></td>";}}

                   echo "</tr>";  
                   echo "</form>";}
                   echo "</table>"; }
                mysqli_close($con);?>
```

first while is working. also Second while is working but not so well. just one time i can see the thumbs up image. i added all code in here about table. any idea?

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: ^ +1, would be good to know what are you trying to achieve, and what's the problem.

Comment: You'll find it useful to halt execution, or have a different control flow to handle the scenario, after printing "Failed to connect to MySQL" (versus trying to do a query on the next line).

Comment: isn't nested loops a bad programming approach?

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code, it appends :

```
{ //first iteration of while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     ... 
     { //first iteration of while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))

     }
     { //Second iteration of while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))

     }
     ...
     { //last iteration of while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))

     }
     // know, $result2 is empty

}
{//Second iteration of while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    ...
    //Here, $result2 is empty, so the second while loop doesn't work
}
```

if you want to reuse $result2, you can store it in an array before, and then use this array in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Your second while loop iterates over the query result stored in `$result2.`
So, the first time the second while loop is executed fully, cursor moves to the end of the table and does not come back to the first position.
One solution would be to store all the values of the second query(whose result is in `$result2`) in another array, and then use that array in the second while loop.
Another solution would be to move the second query itself inside the first while loop, but that would mean that the query will be executed everytime.